# How can I set a dynamic environment variable when building my Spring Boot app as a docker image using buildpacks?

Tags: spring-boot, buildpack

If you check the [commit](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-apprunner-terraform/commit/89c401a777dd5e45ce3e6f4610bfa3e8eca66d29) for the sample aws-apprunner-terraform code (which uses petclinic) you will find that they include in their dockerfile the following:

`ENTRYPOINT env spring.datasource.password=$(aws ssm get-parameter --name /database/password --with-decrypt --region $AWS_REGION | grep Value | cut -d '"' -f4) java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app.jar`

Essentially it is setting the `spring.datasource.password` environment variable dynamically at runtime to retrieve a value from the AWS SSM. This is all fine when using a Dockerfile.

But when I build my application using Spring Boot's in-built `bootBuildImage` task (I use gradle) I'm not sure how to achieve the same effect.

**How can I set a environment variable value to be dynamic like is done in the example above when using the build pack provided by Spring Boot?**

Comment: You should probably ask/request that AWS AppRunner add a custom buildpack/exec.d process to your apps. A buildpack can add an exec.d process which runs before your app starts. The process can set environment variables dynamically. If they included an aws-apprunner buildpack and contribute an exec.d process, they could automatically pull and set these environment variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a `.profile` in the root of your repo with contents like:

```
export MY_VAR=$(some-dynamic-value)
```

More info:
https://github.com/buildpacks/spec/blob/main/buildpack.md#app-interface

Comment: Be careful with `.profile` in Java apps. It can be a little confusing. The `.profile` file must ultimately end up at `/workspace/.profile` in the generated image. With Paketo buildpacks (default for Spring apps), you need to ensure that `.profile` ends up in the root of the executable JAR you generate. You can confirm by running `jar tf <jar>` and making sure you see `.profile` with no leading characters or path.

Answer (score 2):

When using the Spring Boot Gradle plugin's `bootBuildImage` or the Maven plugin's `spring-boot:build-image` with the default [Paketo buildpacks](https://paketo.io/docs/reference/java-reference/), you can use [service bindings](https://github.com/servicebinding/spec) to provide external credentials.

To test this locally, you'd do something like this:

```
$ mkdir -p bindings/db
$ echo "mysql" > bindings/db/type
$ aws ssm get-parameter --name /database/password --with-decrypt --region $AWS_REGION | grep Value | cut -d '"' -f4 > bindings/db/password
```

to end up with this directory structure:

```
bindings
└── db
    ├── password
    └── type
```

When running the application in the container, mount the `bindings` directory to the container and provide an environment variable named `SERVICE_BINDING_ROOT` that points to the `bindings` directory. The [Spring Cloud Bindings](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-bindings) library that the Paketo buildpacks contribute to the app image will do the rest.

I don't know enough about Terraform to advise how best to implement this in the tf scripts.